# call to undefined function submit_button() with ftp form in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error, submit-button, undefined-function

I have a site on Hostgator server, domain and hosting both with Hostgator self hosted wordpress hosting. Suddenly it hit error few days back, instead of loading normal home page its showing FTP client login and fatal error message below. Before contacting host, I deactivated plugin but not resolved even I entered following code in `wp-config.php` file `define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');`

I contacted host, to solve the issue but still they are unable to diagnose the issue, instead they restored site to previous 3 days version when site was working , but this also not solved issue. Also checked with SITE LOCK for malicious code, but found nothing.

Is there any solution that can solve this issue.

Notes:

If site admin logged through mysite.com/wp-admin and browsing mysite.com it loads properly. 
Even after getting error, CTRL+F5 solves this issue and site loads without any issue. 
Issue with non logged end users

This is very strange behaviors. 
[image]
Screen shot attached below

Comment: Connection Information
To perform the requested action, WordPress needs to access your web server. Please enter your FTP credentials to proceed. If you do not remember your credentials, you should contact your web host.
Hostname  
FTP Username  
FTP Password  This password will not be stored on the server. 
Connection Type
 FTP  FTPS (SSL) 
Cancel 
Fatal error: Call to undefined function submit_button() in /home1/wad4gc0acmry/public_html/wp-admin/includes/file.php on line 1264

Answer (score 5):

**Go through the below two possible ways to solve this issue.**

**Way-1:** Add the following FTP information to your **wp-config.php**

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
define('FTP_BASE', '/home1/wad4gc0acmry/public_html/my-site.example.com/wordpress/');
define('FTP_CONTENT_DIR', '/home1/wad4gc0acmry/public_html/my-site.example.com/wordpress/wp-content/');
define('FTP_PLUGIN_DIR ', '/home1/wad4gc0acmry/public_html/my-site.example.com/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/');
// define('FTP_PUBKEY', '/home1/username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub');
// define('FTP_PRIKEY', '/home1/username/.ssh/id_rsa');
define('FTP_USER', 'my-ftp-username');
define('FTP_PASS', 'my-ftp-password');
define('FTP_HOST', 'ftp.my-site.example.com');
// define('FTP_SSL', false);
```

**Way-2:** Give permissions to your wordpress site folder.

**First check PHP process is runing under which user by using the below command**

```
ps aux | grep php
```

**For EX: user is "http" and run the below command.**

```
$ sudo chown -hR http:http PATH_TO_YOUR_WORDPRESS_FOLDER
```

Answer (score 0):

Should I have to use  /home1/wad4gc0acmry/public_html/wp-content/ instead '/home1/wad4gc0acmry/public_html/my-site.example.com/wordpress/wp-content/'

Kindly advise!

As per webhost PHP process is running under 511 user and that user and others have enough permissions to the WP Site.

I have integerated following your code; with CHANGE of actual values of 1) FTP_USER, 2) FTP_PASS, 3) FTP_HOST and 4) my-site.example.com

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
define('FTP_BASE', '/home1/wad4gc0acmry/public_html/my-site.example.com/wordpress/');
define('FTP_CONTENT_DIR', '/home1/wad4gc0acmry/public_html/my-site.example.com/wordpress/wp-content/');
define('FTP_PLUGIN_DIR ', '/home1/wad4gc0acmry/public_html/my-site.example.com/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/');
// define('FTP_PUBKEY', '/home1/username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub');
// define('FTP_PRIKEY', '/home1/username/.ssh/id_rsa');
define('FTP_USER', 'my-ftp-username');
define('FTP_PASS', 'my-ftp-password');
define('FTP_HOST', 'ftp.my-site.example.com');
// define('FTP_SSL', false);
```

At currently site is working for normal users, but i am not confirm if the issue will hit again as this is producing periodically.
In case it will hit again, I will update accordingly.

Thank you very much! juhi